# AngularJS factory without any dependencies injected

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-factory

It is possible to have a factory without dependencies, declaration could be like...

```
//from this...
angular.module('myModule').factory('factoryName',['$http',function($http){
    //TODO code here...
}]);

//to this...
angular.module('myModule').factory('factoryName',[ ,function(){
   //TODO code here...
}]);
```

because I'm using that factory as a singleton object, but browser console throws an angular generic error, so my point is the factory **must** have dependencies injected, thanks

Comment: remove extra comma ...  `[function....` not `[ ,function...`

Answer (score 1):

`angular.module('myModule').factory('factoryName', [function(){}]);`

If you insist on writing the minsafe syntax yourself.  Personally don't write the array syntax manually I just use a gulp or grunt plugin to fill in those strings based on the arguments before it gets passed into minification (it's easy to mess up the order or miss an injection when you have to specify the injectables twice, ngAnnotate is one of the plugins, but search the repo of your build tool and sure you'll find one).

`angular.module('myModule').factory('factoryName', function(){});`
Is fine too since you have no injectables, the array is just for the sake of saving the names of the arguments when minifying the code.